# Enforce existence of cartesian product in join table without triggers in MariaDB 10.2

Tags: mariadb-10.2

Given tables `A`, `B` and `C`, where `C` holds a foreign key to both `A` and `B` (i.e. `C` is a "join table"), is it possible to define a constraint so that `C` contains the whole Cartesian product `A x B` without using triggers in MariaDB 10.2?

(In other words, for every `a` in `A` and every `b` in `B` is is possible to enforce the existence of one `c` in `C` such that `c` has a foreign key to `a` and `b`)

If not, is there a way to redesign the three tables so that the constraint is enforceable, while keeping 4NF?